# how to subclass UITableView to use in other viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm looking to create a subclass for a tableview that I would like to use throughout out all my app. My problem is when I set the `fields` variable the tableview is still empty. I'm assuming that the `fields` variable is not setting right when it is set in the new ViewController. Thank you for the help in advance.

MySubClass

```
import UIKit
import LGButton

class RquestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var fields:[UIView]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewSetup()
    }

    func viewSetup(){
        tableView.register(CustomFormCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: labelReuseCellIdentifier)
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    }
}
//MARK: Delegate
extension RquestTableViewController {
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fields.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.labelReuseCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomFormCell
        let itemView = fields[indexPath.row]
        cell.viewPassed = itemView
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        if let _ = itemView as? UILabel {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)
            return cell
        }
        if let _ = itemView as? UIButton {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)
            return cell
        }
        if let _ = itemView as? LGButton {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)
            return cell
        }
        return  cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }
}
```

MyNewViewController

```
class NewRquestViewController: RquestTableViewController {

    lazy var password:JVFloatLabeledTextField = {
        let v = JVFloatLabeledTextField()
        v.placeholder = "Password"
        return v
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
        fields = [password]
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reloadData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified that `fields` really isn't being set properly? I see no reason why it wouldn't be. But I do see another problem: in addition to overriding `numberOfSections(in:)` and `tableView(_,cellForRowAt:)`, you have to override `tableView(_,numberOfRowsInSection:)`. What you have now is `numberOfSections(in:)` returning the number of fields, but `tableView(_,cellForRowAt:)` is expecting to populate the *rows* with the fields. That means that `tableView(_,cellForRowAt:)` will be called *only* when `section` is `0`, so at most you'd see only one field. Instead, change `numberOfSections(in:)` to return `1`, and implement `tableView(_,numberOfRowsInSection:)` to return `fields.count`.

Comment: Got it working thank you, just to note that the registerCell must be call from the new viewController

Comment: It does? I wouldn’t have even considered that.